# Definition of expectation with condition variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, expectation-maximization

I am having a hard time of digesting this, which is part of EM algorithm that I borrowed Equation 3.2.7 from [https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=363730&seqNum=2#:~:text=3.2%20Traditional%20Derivation%20of%20EM,and%20establishes%20its%20convergence%20property](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=363730&seqNum=2#:%7E:text=3.2%20Traditional%20Derivation%20of%20EM,and%20establishes%20its%20convergence%20property).

My question is related to the "definition of expectation". I spent time on understanding below but can't make sense of conditional part in the expectation, which is "$|X,\theta$" part in the expectation. How does this work? can you provide derivation or related textbook to this?

\begin{align*}
L(\theta) &= \log p(X|\theta) \\
&= \log \left( \sum_z P(Z|X,\theta_n) \frac{p(X,Z|\theta)}{P(Z|X,\theta_n)} \right) \\
&= \log \mathbb{E}_Z \left[ \frac{p(X,Z|\theta)}{P(Z|X,\theta_n)} \Bigg| X, \theta_n \right] & \text{(by definition of expectation)} \\
\end{align*}

I tweaked the equation a bit to show my understanding. Below equation is clear to me that it represents the expectation for Z.
\begin{align*}
L(\theta) &= \log p(X|\theta) \\
&= \log \left( \sum_z P(Z) \frac{p(X,Z|\theta)}{P(Z)} \right) \\
&= \log \mathbb{E}_Z \left[ \frac{p(X,Z|\theta)}{P(Z)}\right] & \text{(by definition of expectation)} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: As I wrote in the main text, the question is: how to understand the first expression. E[...|X, theta]. How to derive this expression? the second equation is pretty clear since it is widely used in probability textbooks. But I am having hard time going from the second equation to the first equation. @Xi'an